# Logs from java.util.logging in ICM

Tags: intershop

In my cartridge I use an external library that logs with `java.util.logging`. I want to redirect the log to SLF4J/logback, but somehow this does not work as I would expect it (logs are empty). Here is the relevant logback configuration:

```
<appender name="PayPal_LogFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>TRACE</level>
    </filter>       
    <File>${intershop.logfile.Directory}/paypal-${intershop.logfile.NamePostfix}.log</File>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <FileNamePattern>${intershop.logfile.Directory}/paypal-${intershop.logfile.NamePostfix}.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>
            [%date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z}] %-5level ${intershop.HostName} ${intershop.InstallationID} ${intershop.ServerName} [%mdc{requestsite}] [%mdc{requestapplication}] %logger [%marker] [%mdc{request.type}] [%mdc{session.id}] [%mdc{request.uuid}] &quot;%thread&quot; %msg %ex%n
        </pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender> 

<logger name="com.paypal" additivity="false">
    <level value="TRACE" />
    <appender-ref ref="Error" />
    <appender-ref ref="PayPal_LogFile" />
</logger>
```

JUL logs in `DEBUG` level, `DEBUG` level is allowed for `com.paypal` and I believe that this should be translated to `INFO` in `SLF4J`. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll [answer my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

The reason for the trouble is the `additivity="false"` property of the logger.

**Background:** Routing from other logging frameworks to SLF4J is generally easy via the so called bridges unless we speak about JUL. See the details [here](https://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html). ICM implements its own bridge between JUL and SLF4J and there is a subtle bug inside. The logging handler of the ICM is attached to the root level and any appender with `additivity="false"` won't work because it will never reach the root level.

The bug seems to be here `com.intershop.beehive.core.internal.log.JavaLoggingAdapter`:

```
handler = new JavaLoggingHandler();
handler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
Logger root = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger(""); 
root.addHandler(handler);
```

I've changed the additivity to `true` although I'm not very happy about this and now I can explore the third party logs.